# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14

Tags: java

Why I am getting string out of index problem with this code.
I have tried a lot of time to get rid of this but I was unable to solve.

I wanted to print maximum substring and minimum substring from a given string of a given characters.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = new String();
        String str1 = new String();
         String str2 = new String();
       str = in.next();
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int i;
        int length = str.length();

         str1=str.substring(0,a); 
       str2=str.substring(0,a);
        for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
            {
            String str3 = new String();
             str3 = str.substring(i,a+i); 
            int x = str1.compareTo(str3);
            int y = str2.compareTo(str3);
            if(x==-32)
            {
                str1 = str3; 
            }
            if(x==32)
                {
                str2=str3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str1);
         System.out.println(str2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here

```
for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
```

If you have a string of n characters this line will loop up to and including index n. That is not what you want. since you start from zero. Effectively you want to loop up to n-1.

So you better of changing it to:

```
for(i=0 ; i < length; i++)
```

Hope that makes sense.

PS. I am not sure if the rest of the code is ok, but this line is definitely causing IOOB exceptions.

Comment: You could include the correct for loop in your post

Comment: This for loop also cause problem because in loop he is using str3 = str.substring(i,a+i);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling

```
in.Close();
```

When you are done using it. Also as mentioned, be wary of out of bounds

```
for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
```

Another thing to note is that this variable is not being used

```
int y = str2.compareTo(str3);
```

And be mindful of unused imports.

Answer (score 0):

First change :

```
str1=str.substring(0,a); 
str2=str.substring(0,a);
```

to:

```
if(a <length){
 str1=str.substring(0,a); 
 str2=str.substring(0,a);
}
```

and Change your for loop from

```
for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
```

to :

```
for(i=0; i < length-a ; i++)
```